# Active Record find using conditions, between two floats

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have tried all the combinations of finds I can think of, and haven't had 100% success.  What's the preferred (or any way that works) way of doing this find:

When using where, I get a cannot iterate over float error.

```
Question.where('id not in (?) AND rating.id = ? AND pvalue BETWEEN ?', not_in, rating_id, 0.0..100.0).limit(25)
```

When using a conditions hash, I can't figure out how to also limit the results to an array.  So I tried two conditions, but I don't think the 'id not in (?) part is ever turned into sql...it returns results that are in the not_in array.

```
Question.find_all_by_rating_id(rating_id, :limit=>25, :conditions => ['id not in (?)', not_in], :conditions=>{:pvalue => 0.0..100.0})
```

The above skips the first condition (it didn't look right having two in there anyways...) and returns

```
SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."rating_id" = 458 AND ("questions"."pvalue" BETWEEN 0.0 AND 100.0) LIMIT 25
```

So I need a combination of the hash condition and the id not in condition.  Any help is appreciated!

notes: pvalue is a float, not_in is an array of ids that I don't want the query to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Question.where("id not in (?) AND rating.id = ? AND pvalue BETWEEN ? AND ?", 
  not_in, 
  rating_id, 
  0.0, 100.0
).limit(25)
```